# How to use 'Where' to read data from Firestore document in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the where clause to find a document in my Firestore database from my google cloud function, this is my code below when I try to just get a document with an ID, it works but when I try to use the where clause it doesn't, how can I fix this? Am I doing anything wrong

```
return await firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).where('APIKEY', '==', '<APIKEY_VALUE>').get().then(doc => {            
  if (!(doc && doc.exists)) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      error: 'Unable to find the document'
    });
  }
  const data = doc.data();
  console.log(data);
  if (!data) {
    return res.status(404).send({
      error: 'Found document is empty'
    });
  }
  return res.status(200).send(data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  return res.status(404).send({
    error: 'Unable to retrieve the document',
    err
  });
});
```

Here is a screenshot of my Firestore database and the document I want to collect:

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work about this code when you run it? If you expect the query to match a document and it doesn't, please edit your question to include a screenshot of the document that you expect to be returned.

Comment: i added the screenshot, please let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Thanks for that. What happens when you run the code? Is there an error? If not, wht response gets sent to the client?

Comment: did you use `firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)` in your query or `firestore.collection('accounts')`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it gives me this error {
  "error": "Unable to find the document"
}

Comment: @PeterO. i used firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)

Comment: Try out my answer.

Comment: What's the value of `COLLECTION_NAME` inside `.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)`?

Comment: Have you've tried using `async` along with `await`? You can check the Firebase documentation on [queries or querying](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries).

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to replace 'COLLECTION_NAME' with the name of the collection
you want to find.

Replace `firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)` with `firestore.collection('accounts')`